# Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Query\Builder serialization breaks mongo connection

Tags: php, serialization, mongodb, doctrine-orm

I have an object that has an instance of Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Query\Builder . When I serialize my object, unserialize it, and then try to use the Builder, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'The MongoCursor object has not been correctly initialized by its constructor'

I assume that this is because PHP looses its connection to the mongo server in the serialization process. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The only thing you can do is to remove that object on serialization and create a new one on unserialization. See the [serializable interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) in PHP.